# How is it possible to break encrypted public key (RSA) using password as symmetric key?

Tags: public-key, encryption-symmetric, cryptanalysis

Given public key (RSA) encrypted with symmetric key (password) and if password is weak, then how is it possible to find password using given encrypted public key only.

Comment: Besides that you'll normally not encrypt the public key (the purpose of it is being public), a weak password can always be found using brute force.

Comment: @PMF if the public key is ephimeral then how is it possible to find by brute force?

Comment: I don't exactly know what ephemeral means here, but when you get something encrypted, you can always use brute force to crack it.